# loading numbers in a text file using C

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to write a program that loads numbers in a text file into an array. The text file is called "numbers" and the numbers are in the following format: 3,49,52,40,34 etc..

When I try to run the program, I get a "program is not responding error". Could anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 32

int main (void) {

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen ("numbers.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        puts ("No data in file");
        return 0;

    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int a[MAX];

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d, ", &n) > 0) {
        a[i++] = n;
    }

    fclose (fp);

    printf ("Data loaded");

    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
        printf ("%d", a[j++]);
        printf ("THE END");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the bracket in the `if` condition which causes the program to return without closing the file handle.

Comment: Missing {} after your `if (fp == NULL)` means you'll always execute the return 0.

Comment: thank you so much! I can;t believe i missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the bracket in the `if` condition:

```
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen ("numbers.txt", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    puts ("No data in file");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fp == NULL)
    puts ("No data in file");
    return 0;
```

Same as:

```
if (fp == NULL)
    puts ("No data in file");
return 0; //returned already
```

Your program already returns without reading from the file.

You should do

```
if (fp == NULL)
{  
    puts ("No data in file");
    return 0; 
}
```